# Avoiding key construction for std::map::find()

Tags: c++, c++11

Suppose I've got a `std::map<std::string, int>`. `std::string` can be compared to C strings (const char*) without `std::string` temporaries. However, `map::find()` appears to force me to construct a temporary `std::string`, which probably requires a memory allocation. How do I avoid this? Conceptually it's easy, but the STL appears to prevent this.

```
#include <map>

int main()
{
    std::map<std::string, int> m;
    m.find("Olaf");
}
```

Comment: If you are using a map of `string` keys then under the covers and in building the map, a lot of invisible `string` allocations are already happening. Is this really worth worrying about? Most apps have other perf concerns that would rank higher.  You could avoid this by isolating the magic values in a static "MyConstants" class maybe.

Comment: @SteveTownsend Most/all of those allocations will be happening on insert though, if you had a high performance method of querying the map which perfomed no allocations, that might be neat...

Comment: @Benj - `map::find` will not result in an obvious allocation anyway, unless the input requires `string` construction (as here, via implicit conversion)

Comment: @SteveTownsend - True, if only `std::string` could perform copy-on-write when constructed with a `const char *`.

Comment: @Steve: They're not invisible and might not be a lot. It's one allocation per key (with move semantics).

Comment: @Benj: That'd be cool but it doesn't solve the generic problem.

Comment: Well, if you really want to put effort on it, you could write a wrapper around std::map only for string and provide two methods for find. One for std::string and one for const char*, but it is a lot of work for a such small impact on performance.

Comment: If the string is really that small then the small string optimization will avoid any allocation when constructing the string. For example libc++ std::string on x86_64 allows strings of up to 22 char long without dynamic allocation. VS11 allows up to 15.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Your concern is real, and there's no good workaround for C++11.

C++14 fixes this issue by adding a templated overload of `std::map::find` — the relevant proposal is [N3657](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2013/n3657.htm). In C++14, your program would look like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <map>
#include <algorithm>

class std_string {
    char *m_s;
public:
    std_string() { m_s = nullptr; }
    std_string(const char* s) { puts("Oops! A new std_string was constructed!"); m_s = strdup(s); }
    ~std_string() { free(m_s); }
    std_string(std_string&& ss) = delete;
    std_string(const std_string& ss) = delete;
    std_string& operator=(std_string&& ss) = delete;
    std_string& operator=(const std_string& ss) = delete;

    bool operator< (const char* s) const { return strcmp(m_s, s) < 0; }
    bool operator< (const std_string& ss) const { return strcmp(m_s, ss.m_s) < 0; }
    friend bool operator< (const char* s, const std_string& ss) { return strcmp(s, ss.m_s) < 0; }
};

int main()
{
    {
        puts("The C++11 way makes a copy...");
        std::map<std_string, int> m;
        auto it = m.find("Olaf");
    }
    {
        puts("The C++14 way doesn't...");
        std::map<std_string, int, std::less<>> m;
        auto it = m.find("Olaf");
    }
}
```

(`std::less<>` is the generalized "less-than" comparator, equivalent to `operator<`. C++03 and C++11 have a broken-by-design version of this comparator that forces both arguments to be the same type. C++14 finally does it right.)

Unfortunately the Committee seems to have decided that people should go through all their C++11 code and update every container to use `std::less<>` as the comparator — it doesn't just happen by default. There's no good reason for this decision; it's just The Way It Is. (See my comments above about broken-by-design. C++ has a bad habit of introducing broken versions of things before introducing the "real" versions several years later.)

For C++11, `std::map::find` has only one overload (the one that takes `const Key&`), so any workaround will necessarily involve changing the `Key` type to be less expensive — we can't just fiddle with the comparator, because by the time execution reaches the comparator, we've already promoted `find`'s argument to the `Key` type.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <map>
#include <algorithm>

class std_string {
    char *m_s;
public:
    std_string() : m_s(nullptr) { }
    std_string(const char* s) : m_s(strdup(s)) { puts("Oops! A new std_string was constructed!"); }
    ~std_string() { free(m_s); }
    std_string(std_string&& ss) : m_s(nullptr) { std::swap(m_s, ss.m_s); }
    std_string(const std_string& ss) : m_s(strdup(ss.data())) { puts("Oops! A new std_string was constructed!"); }
    std_string& operator=(std_string&& ss) = delete;
    std_string& operator=(const std_string& ss) = delete;

    const char* data() const { return m_s; }

    bool operator< (const char* s) const { return strcmp(m_s, s) < 0; }
    bool operator< (const std_string& ss) const { return strcmp(m_s, ss.m_s) < 0; }
    friend bool operator< (const char* s, const std_string& ss) { return strcmp(s, ss.m_s) < 0; }
};

struct string_or_ptr {
    union {
        const char* ptr;
        alignas(std_string) unsigned char str[sizeof (std_string)];
    } m_u;
    bool m_deep;

    char const* & ptr() { return m_u.ptr; }
    std_string& str() { return *reinterpret_cast<std_string*>(m_u.str); }
    char const* const & ptr() const { return m_u.ptr; }
    std_string const& str() const { return *reinterpret_cast<const std_string*>(m_u.str); }

    string_or_ptr() : m_deep(false) { ptr() = ""; }
    string_or_ptr(const char* s) : m_deep(false) { ptr() = s; }
    string_or_ptr(std_string&& s) : m_deep(true) { new ((void*)&str()) std_string(std::move(s)); }
    string_or_ptr(const std_string& s) : m_deep(true) { new ((void*)&str()) std_string(s); }
    ~string_or_ptr() { if (m_deep) str().~std_string(); }
    std_string& operator=(std_string&& ss) = delete;
    std_string& operator=(const std_string& ss) = delete;


    operator const char*() const { return m_deep ? str().data() : ptr(); }

    bool operator< (const char* s) const { return strcmp((const char*)*this, s) < 0; }
    bool operator< (const std_string& ss) const { return (const char*)*this < ss; }
    bool operator< (const string_or_ptr& sp) const { return strcmp((const char*)*this, (const char*)sp) < 0; }
    friend bool operator< (const char* s, const string_or_ptr& sp) { return strcmp(s, (const char*)sp) < 0; }
    friend bool operator< (const std_string& ss, const string_or_ptr& sp) { return ss < (const char*)sp; }
};

int main()
{
    {
        puts("The C++11 way...");
        std::map<std_string, int> m;
        auto it = m.find("Olaf");
    }
    {
        puts("The C++11 way with a custom string-or-pointer Key type...");
        std::map<string_or_ptr, int> m;
        auto it = m.find("Olaf");
    }
}
```

Comment: *"There's no good reason for this decision; it's just The Way It Is."* Wrong. Consider there exists for some type `stupid_string` only a converting constructor from `char const*` but not a comparison operator `operator<(stupid_string const&, char const*)`, only `operator<(stupid_string const&, stupid_string const&)`. Since `std::less<>` will forward to the comparison operator, **each comparison will create a new `stupid_string`**. I've seen this problem in real code some years ago, since STLPort (IIRC) does this by default as a non-conforming extension.

Comment: @dyp That seems like a good reason not to write `stupid_string`, but it doesn't seem like a good reason for the compiler to generate slow code for `std::map<smart_string, int>`. ("Make stupid code slow and smart code fast" seems to me like a *strictly better* philosophy than "make stupid code fail to compile and make smart code slow.") In other words, I disagree as to whether the above bit of trivia constitutes a "*good* reason" for the Committee to have pessimized the default implementations of `std::map` and `std::set`.

Comment: The idea is that old code stays as fast as it is (and doesn't get slower), and new code can use the new function object types. It is also a correctness issue -- in the problem I encountered it led to UB.

Comment: *broken-by-design* will look just fine alongside with *ill-formed* on cppreference

Answer (score 2):

There isn't actually a way to force `find` to use a comparison operator different from the one used to create the `map`. If you could pass a different one into `find`, how could it guarantee that both comparisons would provide the same ordering?

Instead, just think about the cases:

1) You're passing around `char*` in your program. In this case, just don't do that. Use `std::string` instead, creating it one time if needed, as close to the origination as possible. Then no conversion is needed.

2) You're trying to find string literals. In this case, why is the key a `string`? Make the key be a nicely named enumerated type instead:

```
enum names { OLAF };
map<names, int> m;
m.find(OLAF);
```

3) You want to find *both* strings and C-string literals. In this case, I would create a global lookup table of strings indexed by an enumeration but built once at the start of main. Then you would call something like `m.find(global_strings[OLAF]);`

EDIT: You seem very focused/concerned about the performance implications of `string` here. Have you profiled your application and found that `string`'s allocations are a significant portion of your app's time? I would of course believe this on embedded systems/devices.

Additionally, you've tagged your question C++ but you seem to be outright refusing to use C++'s built in string feature which does far more than "cost you performance". It provides a variety of helpful functions/methods/operators but most importantly it manages the memory for you so you don't spend days or weeks hunting down those truly insidious bugs that no doubt will crop up.

If you're reading variable length data from the network I can't quite grasp the performance difference between `char* buffer = new char[needed_size];` and something like `std::string s; s.resize(needed_size);` other than that using `string` provides some safety and memory management for you.

Comment: I don't need a different comparison operator, operator< is fine. 1. This is a specific example, but the problem is generic. Using std::string buys me nothing but a performance hit. 2. Maybe, maybe not. The string might come from a network packet. Why would I have to copy it into a std::string just to be able to use it?

Comment: @XTF There's nothing to stop you creating a map<char *, int> with a comparator which performs strcmp().  Just remember to delete all your pointers when you clear the map.

Comment: @Benj: You're not seriously suggesting me to use dumb owning pointers, are you? This is C++11, not C.

Comment: @XTF I'm suggesting that if you're concerns are so low level then perhaps C isn't such a bad idea ;-)

Comment: @Benj: Again, the network packet was just an example. I actually use array for the buffer and the string would certainly not be the entire buffer. C is a *bad* idea. There's no need to give up C++ if performance is a goal.

Comment: @XTF What it looks like to us from your comments: You tell us you want to use C++ in a certain way, but unfortunately it doesn't support that; I suggest alternate options, you say they won't work. At this point it really does look like you want C here.

Answer (score 1):

If the construction of a string from a literal is really a measured performance bottleneck for you, you can use your own class instead of a `std::string` that holds either a string or a pointer to a literal. The downside is some extra complication, plus adding the size of a pointer to the elements you're inserting into the container. Note that the value is immutable as required by `map`, so it's safe to store the results of `c_str`.

```
class mystring
{
    std::string  str;
    const char * value;
public:
    mystring() : value(NULL)
    {
    }
    void setString(const std::string & s)
    {
        assert(value == NULL);
        str = s;
        value = str.c_str();
    }
    void setLiteral(const char * s)
    {
        assert(value == NULL);
        value = s;
    }
    bool operator<(const mystring & rhs)
    {
        return strcmp(literal, rhs.literal) < 0;
    }
};

std::map<mystring, int> m;
mystring text;
text.setString(some_key);
m.insert(std::make_pair(text, some_data));
// ...
mystring key;
key.setLiteral("Olaf");
m[key] = new_value;
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to specifically define a comparator for `map::find()` function. Instead I would advice you to use create your comparator (myOwnCmp) and delcare a `std::map<char*, int, myOwnCmp>` for your program. For very large programs or when the number of testcases are very high, it will be comparatively faster than `std::map<string, int>` because the time spend to create a string by calling the string constructor and later calling its destructor consumes significant amount of time. Using const char* as the key will only involve pointer comparison.

The only thing you need to take care of is to make a separate local copy of the char* coming as an argument when you are populating the map by overriding the insert function or by creating your own add function, because there are chances that the pointer can later be modified or deleted. So you want to make sure that you have kept a local copy of the char* before adding it as the key to the map.

The code would go something like this:-

```
 struct myOwnComp {
        bool operator()(const char* a, const char* b) const {
            return (strcmp(a, b) < 0);
        }
    };

std::map<char*, int, myOwnComp> mymap;

void addToMap(char*& ref, int value)
{
    char *key = new char[strlen(ref) + 1]{};
    std::copy(ref, ref + strlen(ref), key);
    mymap[key] = value;
}
```