# Why is heterogenous std::*map lookup opt-in in C++?

Tags: c++, containers, c++14

To support heterogeneous key lookup for a `std::map` one has to be a bit more verbose that in the olden days: (taken from the [question on **how** to do it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10536788/avoiding-key-construction-for-stdmapfind))

```
int main()
{
    {
        puts("The C++11 way makes a copy...");
        std::map<std_string, int> m;
        auto it = m.find("Olaf");
    }
    {
        puts("The C++14 way doesn't...");
        std::map<std_string, int, std::less<>> m;
        auto it = m.find("Olaf");
    }
}
```

Also see: https://www.cppstories.com/2021/heterogeneous-access-cpp20/ for an explanation.

From this link and from the linked question (and also from N3657) there a a few scattered reasons given as to why this is opt-in. Since I had to do quite some scrolling and I didn't find a succinct summary of the reasons, I would like to put together a summary here that every junior dev understands, as to

> Why stupid C++ makes me write that extra `std::less<>` ??! Why doesn't it just allow transparent heterogeneous comparison with the default type we always used?

;-)

Comment: are you asking why you have to be more verbose in C++14 or why the change was made ?

Comment: Backward compatibility is the answer. Extra feature can't give side effects on already existing code (or remove them).

Comment: @MarekR - yeah *I* know that now after reading several pages of fluff. But "because backwards compat" is not a very nice answer. Hence I think one should try to summarize this here. (Not that other's haven't done this in some form or other, but I think we can do better here :-)

Comment: Probably you have to find some paper which introduce this new feature into C++14. I'm pretty sure it was considered to alter default value for some templates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `std::map` would simple support this silently, that is if `std::map<KeyT, ValT>` would support `find(LookupT)` for "any compatible" type then:

- The [abseil page on the matter](https://abseil.io/tips/144) cites an implicit comparison between `double` and `int`that would be trouble:

> implicitly supporting heterogeneous lookup can be dangerous, as the relationship
> between values might not be maintained after conversions.
> For example, `1.0 < 1.1`, but `static_cast<int>(1.0) == static_cast<int>(1.1)`.
> Thus, using a `double` to look up a value in a `std::set<int>` could lead to incorrect results.

- Performance(!) - old code with types that do not support heterogeneous comparison would start to run *slower*: [dyp wrote](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10536788/avoiding-key-construction-for-stdmapfind#comment37668377_24360490):

> Consider there exists for some type `stupid_string` only a converting constructor
> from `char const*` but not a comparison operator `operator<(stupid_string const&,  char const*)`, only `operator<(stupid_string const&, stupid_string const&)`.
> Since `std::less<>` ((would)) forward to the comparison operator, each comparison will create a new stupid_string.

((instead of just creating the extra comparison object once on the call site of std::find))

Answer (score 1):

The `map` template has a default comparison

```
template<
    class Key,
    class T,
    class Compare = std::less<Key>,
    class Allocator = std::allocator<std::pair<const Key, T> >
> class map;
```

Suppose you wanted a `map<my_type, int>` and enabled that by specializing `std::less<my_type>` (which is then selected by the default).

Then C++14 couldn't just start using unspecialized  `std::less<>` instead. So you have to explicitly ask for it!

Comment: Sorry, that's kinda missing the point. If I'd specialized `std::less` for a type, OK. But why would this not work out of the box for the unspecialized std::less -- that's really what people are asking. (Hint: I've seen a few reasons listed, and yours is not one of them as far as I can tell.)

Comment: @Martin - My point *is*  that you can use `map<my_type, int>` and it picks up the specialization `std::less<my_type>`. You don't have to mention it when declaring variables. If the standard then were to replace this with `std::less<>` you'd get a comparison using `operator<`. which might not have been specialized for the map use. The whole reason for a specialized `less<my_type>` is that set/map need that, but you might not want comparison operators defined for the type.