# Should std::string specialize std::less with support for heterogeneous lookup?

Tags: c++, std

Being able to look up a `char*` in a container with `find` *without* needing to create a temporary string object is a [Good Thing](https://www.cppstories.com/2021/heterogeneous-access-cpp20/). See: [Avoiding key construction for std::map::find()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10536788/avoiding-key-construction-for-stdmapfind) and https://www.cppstories.com/2021/heterogeneous-access-cpp20/ and ...

[There are reasons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72473815/why-is-heterogenous-stdmap-lookup-opt-in-in-c) why C++ could not enable this for any type `T` used as a key type.

So, as of C++20/23 we are AFAIKT left with:

```
int main()
{
    {
        // Slow, constructs temporary
        std::map<std_string, int> m;
        auto it = m.find("Olaf");
    }
    {
        // "Fast" does not need to construct temporary
        std::map<std_string, int, std::less<>> m;
        auto it = m.find("Olaf");
    }
}
```

**However** - I was wondering why `std::string` doesn't automatically opt-in to this by providing a (partial?) specialization for `std::less<std::string>`? Has this simply not been specified yet, or are there any legitimate reasons why `std::string` (or rather `std::basic_string<...>`) cannot do this?

Comment: you can also do `m.find("Olaf"s)` and you will have just 1 allocation.

Comment: @bolov in that case SSO will likely kick in and no allocation is needed at all in `std::string`. Even better if you can use `m.find("Olaf"sv)`, no `std::string` involved

Comment: @phuclv yes, I meant 1 temporary. With string view you have the same problem as with char*: a bunch of string temporaries will be created

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the primary reason is that nobody proposed it. Nothing happens by magic, it has to be proposed by somebody and then reviewed and approved. If the proposal step doesn't happen, nothing will change.

However, it should be noted that making `std::less<std::string>` transparent would be a breaking change for types like:

```cpp
class StupidString
{
  std::string m_str1;
  std::string m_str2;
public:
  // Constructors etc. ...

  operator std::string() const { return m_str1; }

  std::strong_ordering operator<=>(const std::string& s) const
  { return m_str2 <=> s; }
};
```

This class behaves differently when compared directly to a `std::string` or when converted to `std::string` first and then compared.

Today, passing an instance of this class to `map<string, int>::find(const string&)` would implicitly convert to `std::string` and so use `m_str1`. But if `std::less<std::string>` was transparent, it would compare using `m_str2`. That would change behaviour.

Arguably, this class is stupid and deserves to break. Since the addition of `<=>` the language is much less forgiving of inconsistent comparisons with this kind of odd behaviour. But breaking changes always need to be considered carefully, even if the code that would break looks stupid at first glance.

It would be possible to make `std::less<std::string>` able to compare directly to *just* `const char*` and `std::string_view` without conversions (which is already true for `operator<`), e.g.

```cpp
template<>
struct less<string>
{
  bool operator()(const string&, const string&) const noexcept;
  // Not in the standard today:
  bool operator()(const string&, string_view) const noexcept;
  bool operator()(const string&, const char*) const noexcept;
  bool operator()(string_view, const string&) const noexcept;
  bool operator()(const char*, const string&) const noexcept;
};
```

But this could also be a breaking change. A type that is convertible to `std::string` and `const char*` (or `std::string` and `std::string_view`) would now be unable to be passed to `std::less<std::string>` because it would become ambiguous. That can be solved, e.g.

```cpp
template<typename T>
concept string_view_or_char_ptr
   = same_as<string_view> || same_as<T, const char*> || same_as<T, char*>;

template<>
struct less<string>
{
  bool operator()(const string&, const string&) const noexcept;
  // Not in the standard today:
  template<string_view_or_char_ptr T>
  bool operator()(const string&, T) const noexcept;
  template<string_view_or_char_ptr T>
  bool operator()(T, const string&) const noexcept;
};
```

But this wouldn't actually help. Because this specialization doesn't define the `is_transparent` member (because it's not fully transparent, because it only accepts three types, not anything comparable with `std::string`), the associative containers would not define the additional function templates that take an arbitrary key. And so the extra `less<string>::operator()` overloads wouldn't be used, and you'd still get a conversion to `std::string` when you do `find("Olaf")`.

Sorry.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough explanation. I just hope "someone" will propose the (breaking change) for less<string> -- with the containers it seemed reasonable to keep the old behavior, but with std::string my feeling is that breaking things would make more sense here :-)

Comment: Feels silly that simply providing a less with  operator(string, string) + operator(string_view, string) + operator(string, string_view)   fails when looking up with `"haha"`. IMO the compiler should know that "haha" is better converted to string_view than to std::string. Maybe the language should provide some tools to do this?

Comment: Maybe somebody should propose it. Nothing happens otherwise.